# High RAM usage, not seen in task manager

Tags: windows-7, memory, services

I am using Windows 7 64-bit 7600, with 4Gb of RAM.
I have a serious problem, since something uses a lot of RAM(3.94Gb) and I see "stairs" in taskmanager, it rises to +3Gb RAM and it drops to about 2Gb and then rises slowly again, and suddenly drops.
I tryed installing this version again and other versions, newer ones, but no effect.
Ive even tryed disconnecting other harddrives while I installed it, and then installed NOD32 and updated it.

How could I know what is using that much RAM?

P.S.: I was suspecting superfetch service, I disabled it, restarted pc, and it didnt work, since the memory is the highest point when I login with password, it is really annoying since I need about 1minute to see my desktop, neither alone try anything else. After loging in it slowly drops and after random time it starts rising again. That doesnt happen immediately after a fresh windows install. And how the drivers go, I tryed older drivers for GPU, and newest ones.

Comment: server...fault, serverfault, faults with servers...

Comment: while this does belong on superuser- you shuold realize that you want windows to use up all of yuor ram, you should not be disabling superfetch.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to gain more information through using the
  [Microsofts Sys Internals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx)

Especially the tools Process Monitor and Process Explorer

These are the tools created by Mark Russinovich, who is now a Sr. Microsoft reasearch fellow.  Great for exploring your system and what it is doing!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: you are seeing heavy usage in the "Physical Memory Usage History" under the performance tab of the task manager?

Under the processes tab, the column named "Memory (Private Working Set)" should show you any processes with outstanding memory usage. If you don't see it, check its box under View > Select Columns...

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Jeremy, Process Explorer is a great tool at finding out which program is being a memory hog.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

I think by default it only list CPU usage so at the column headers, you'll need to right click , choose "Select Columns", and add "Working Set Size" under the Process Memory tab. I also like having "I/O Delta Read Bytes" and "I/O Delta Write Bytes" from Process Performance.

Also, high memory usage is not necessarily a problem. Unless you are writing to swap constantly and out of available memory, operating systems generally tend to not free of memory unless its needs to (it's like clearing your desk when you still got space to do work). If it cleared the memory every time you stopped using something and then went back to use it, that would waste time (like with the table analogy, getting rid of your pens and paper when you're just going to use it 5 mins later).

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to open your resource monitor..thats there in performance of task manager......it will show which process does so ..and consequently suspend the process...